# How to open a URL in the App, if installed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xamarin.forms, deep-linking

I have a web app, and when someone inserts a new order, some users have chosen to receive a link to that new order (example: www.myulr/orders/34).

Now I also have a Xamarin Forms app (it's a webview that just loads the website for now).

When they click on the link from a phone, is it possible to open the app, if they have it installed?

If it is, how can I do that? Ideally it would recognize that they have the app installed, and it would automatically point the webview to that url.

I hear about deep-linking but i can't figure out how to make it work (and if it is the right solution).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Branch](http://branch.io) has a solution for Xamarin deeplinking and the base product should be free. [Xamarin Docs](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/xamarin-branch-deep-linking)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look on this to see how deep link works on xamarin.forms.
     https://blog.xamarin.com/deep-link-content-with-xamarin-forms-url-navigation/